# Lower bound on speed of $L_1$ Cesaro convergence

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

The a question is to show that Cesaro sums converge slowly

$||f - \sigma_Nf||_{L_2} \geq ||f||_2/N$,

where $\sigma_N f$ is the Cesaro sum of $\hat{f}(n)$, that is the convolusion of Fejer kenerl and f.

It can be solved by noting $||f - \sigma_Nf||_{L_2}^2 = \sum|\widehat{f - \sigma_Nf}(n)|^2$ and with another assumption $\hat{f}(0) = 0$.

But what shall I do with the $L_1$ norm? i.e., what is the lower bound for $||f - \sigma_Nf||_1$?

Thank you for any hints!

Comment: Try $a_{n+1}-\frac{n}{n+1}a_n(T(x))$

Comment: Could you go into detail a little bit?

Comment: sure, what exactly is your $\sigma_N$?

Comment: Oh I forgot to write down. I edited again, it's the Cesaro mean sum of Fourier coeficients of f.